# How to get offline minified version of office-js only for Excel Add-in

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

How to get offline minified version of officejs only for Excel add-in.
I understand that we should always use officejs from CDN, but our customer doesn't always use a machine which has internet access. Also the offline version we get from npm is huge around 50 mb. I have created add-in only for Excel and I don't think, I need files related to outlook or word.

Or

If anybody can suggest me as which file from officejs npm package to use, I will ship those files for Excel add-in that would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll see the files in a folder structure like this:

```
\Office
   \1
    (various language string folders)
    (various host and platform specific JS files)
    Office.debug.js
    (a few other files that are used by all hosts/platforms)
   \metadata
```

What you need to ship are The files for your customer's language, the Office.debug.js, all the files that are used by all hosts/platforms, the files in the \metadata folder, and the excel* files for your customer's host and platforms. It may take some experimentation to get exactly the right set.